# how to make whole widget area clickable?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, android-widget

I have a widget with a button, an image and a title and a black background (linear layout). These views are separately clickable. But how to treat all as a single item? (like androids default power widget has an icon and a green bar at bottom but acts as a whole and an orange border is shown on press). i need on click whole widget area is lit and again on click whole widget area is greyed. e.g an invisible button covering the whole widget area is also ok. thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the child views you need: [`android:clickable="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable) and [`android:duplicateParentState="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState). This causes the child views to not be clickable and to also take on the parent view's state (e.g., pressed). For the parent view you need to set [`android:clickable="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable). To make it clickable. Then you only handle the onClick event from the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Views, just like buttons, have the [setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method. By setting `android:clickable="true"` in the XML, you can handle the `onClick` the same as you would handle it for any other object.